# How can I set my compass direction in always to the west?

Tags: android, google-maps, compass-geolocation, direction

I make a Google map where compass automatically directs north.
But I have to make this compass's indicator always to the West.
How can i do it?Any ideas?Do i need to perform any special terms?
Please Help me :(

Comment: `@Override
     public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      
      MyLocationOverlay me.enableCompass();}` I am just enable the compass and it automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

[bearing from north + 90°] modulo(360)

Derive your own class from MyLocationOverlay. 
Override drawCompass(); 
Manipulate the Canvas object you're handed as necessary. 
Call super.drawCompass() to draw the compass at your new location. 
Restore the Canvas to how you found it.

protected void drawCompass(android.graphics.Canvas canvas,float bearing) is the key for what you want!! with few changes in the bearing value after getting north bearing

Comment: how can i set it in my map activity?

Comment: Derive your own class from MyLocationOverlay. 
Override drawCompass(); 
Manipulate the Canvas object you're handed as necessary. 
Call super.drawCompass() to draw the compass at your new location. 
Restore the Canvas to how you found it.

Comment: Have you any useful link which help me more perfectly?